# Why isn't there an official docker image for QGIS server, i.e. released by QGIS.org

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, docker

As of November 21, 2021, the top 3 G..gle results when searching for "docker hub qgis server" are:

- [kartoza/qgis-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/qgis-server/)
- [camptocamp(qgis-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/qgis-server)
- [openquake/qgis-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/openquake/qgis-server)

There is also a nice documentation on how to set it up natively: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/index.html

But for those who are not much into configuring web servers, the learning curve may be steep.

Therefore, I am naively wondering; why isn't there an "official" docker image for QGIS server, by official, I mean maintained and published by QGIS.org itself and not by third parties?

Comment: Perhaps the developers of QGIS server feel that they can spend their time better for developing the server than for building Docker images, especially because there are third parties who are specialized on that? I guess that it is impossible to make one Docker that makes everybody happy so the need for third party versions or self-built images would still remain. Is there something that does not work for you in the third party containers?